# Fill Font-awesome icon with CSS only

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, font-awesome

I want to add animation to my Font-awesome Heart icon, i want to have a wave effect on hover and click.

And it should be empty otherwise not black, like the `far fa-heart`.
But i don't know how, and i've been on this for hours

I have this for now

```css
.plop{
      height: 200px;
  }

#wrap{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:0px;
}
  
#banner {
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
    }
    
.fill {
        animation-name: fillAction;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        mix-blend-mode:screen;
    }
    
#waveShape{
        animation-name: waveAction;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        fill: #04ACFF;
    }

#wrap i{
    position: absolute;
    font-size:25px; 
    background:#fff;
    }

  @keyframes fillAction {
    0% {
      transform: translate(0, 25px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translate(0, -25px);
    }
  }
  @keyframes waveAction {
    0% {
      transform: translate(-45px, 0);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8ac5de0510.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<section class="plop">
    <div id="wrap">
                <i class="fas fa-heart" id="banner"></i>
        <div class="fill">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="50px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" xml:space="preserve">
              <path id="waveShape" d="M 300 300 V 2.5 c 0 0 0 -0.5 -1 0.5 c 0.1 2.6 
              -28 6 -40.5 -2.4 c -3.5 -1.6 -40.6 2.4 -40.6 2.4 c -12.3 1.1 -23.9 5 
              -31.9 6 c -2 -0.1 -27.1 2.4 -32 -1.9 c 0 0 -33.1 -7.7 -40.1 -5.7 c -18.1 
              10.4 -40.8 2.4 -40.8 2.4 c -7.3 -1 -19.1 -2.8 -32.1 5.2 c -7 4 -20 -1 
              -32.2 -1.9 c 0 0 -3.1 -0.3 -8.1 -0.7 V 300 H 300 z"/>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Zlastaneur/x24konag/

Comment: the question isn't clear if you want the icon to be empty before hover then color: transparent will work. Please provide detail of what you want to do, so we can further help you in this.

Comment: @RaashidDinDar unfortunately I don’t think color transparent will work because the animation is relying on mix blend mode:screen so there’ll have to be some change there.

Comment: When you say the heart should be empty to start with, is it OK if it is white rather than transparent?

Comment: so you want to add animation to the icon on hover. Then it would be better to add hover styling to an icon like #banner:hover { CSS properties including animation here }. check hover pseudo property

Comment: Just to note that the given code gives a different effect when used with the more recent versions of Fontawesome (they use SVG to render the icons).